# Inverse of RegEx that checks for certain characters?

Tags: regex

I need to provide a list of regex for validating certain input, for example, the input must be within 4-8 characters:

```
(.){4,9}
```

But there's one requirement that the input cannot contain certain characters, I could figure out how I can check if the input does contain those characters:

```
[<=>]
```

But how do I make it so that it matches anything that DOESN'T contain those characters?

I thought about negating the set:

```
[^<=>]
```

But it matches as long as there's some character that's not in the set.

Thanks!

Update:

So here are a list of input and expected behaviours:

Input: `OK`
Expected: failed to match `(.){4,9}`, length is less than 4

Input: `1+1=2`
Expected: failed to match the regex that input cannot contain restricted characters, in this case, the equal sign `=`

Comment: Can you add an input string and the expected output ?

Comment: Why not `^[^<=>]{4,9}$`?

Comment: @mousetail Yes that works, I guess the system wants to map each RegEx to a reason why it doesn't match, so if I combine two rules into one RegEx it can be difficult to show the reason why the input is not valid.

Comment: You can add both regexes